# Serialize binary field django rest framework

Tags: serialization, base64, django-rest-framework

I'm having difficulties to save a Base64 string through a serializer. I'm using django rest framework 2.4 and django 1.7. The model and serializer are as follow:

models.py

```
class TicketAttachmentAreas(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Tickets)
    attachment_file = models.ForeignKey(AttachmentFiles, related_name='areas')
    x1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    x2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    y1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    y2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    paint_data = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class TicketAttachmentAreasSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ticket = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    attachment_file = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = TicketAttachmentAreas
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'ticket', 'paint_data', 'attachment_file')
```

I'm simply trying to save data through the serializer with the following code:

```
serializer = TicketAttachmentAreasSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

Unfortunately, even though I have my base64 in data['paint_data'], serializer.data['paint_data'] is empty and thus not saved.

I'm guessing DRF modelSerializer does not recognize BinaryField and would need something like a serializers.BinaryField, or use a methodField to set it, but I'm very new to it and have currently no idea how to do this properly, so I'd really appreciate your help !

(currently I'm using the following work-around, but it's quite ugly:)

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    ticket_attachment_area = serializer.save()
    if 'paint_data' in data.keys():
        ticket_attachment_area.paint_data = base64.encodestring(data['paint_data'])
        ticket_attachment_area.save()
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [writing a custom serializer field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) and using it in your serializer. You can specify how you want to convert between strings and bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your help this part of the documentation has slipped out of me.

Comment: It would be nice to have a solution which works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Django serializer is not fetching binary field value.
You have to declare Charfield in serializer.

```
TicketAttachmentAreasSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ticket = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    attachment_file = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    **paint_data = serializers.CharField()**
```