# How to insert image using Django BinaryField and Postgresql Bytea with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, bytea

I want to insert image to database.

I use Django Rest Framework and Django BinaryField in model and use Postgresql Bytea data type.

This is my code :

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    question_picture = models.BinaryField(default=None, null=True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mc_a = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mc_b = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mc_c = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'question'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

**serializers.py**

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_id',
                  'question',
                  'question_picture',
                  'answer',
                  'mc_a',
                  'mc_b',
                  'mc_c')
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def question_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            question_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            questions_serializer = QuestionSerializer(data=question_data)
            if questions_serializer.is_valid():
                questions_serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(questions_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
            return JsonResponse(questions_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

With the above code that I tried to run to insert data. When I checked the database, the `question_picture` data (image) was **empty**, but the other data was filled.

How do I insert the image so that it can be stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

How you send the image to Django? (Base64?).

I think this thread is similar to yours [Serialize binary field django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28630769/7157724)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).